# Elastic data migration issue migrating from 2.3.4 to 5.5.2

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, upgrade, kibana-5

In our application, we are using the elastic search of 2.3.4 and kibana 4.5.3 version. It has already indexed data. Recently, we decided to upgrade elastic search to 5.5.2 version and kibana to 5.5.2 version.

Some time back, we had upgraded elastic search from 1.x to 2.3.4. At that time, we had re-indexed the data as part of migration.

From the elastic search and kibana upgrade document, we are not clear on re-indexing the current data in upgrading ES from 2.x to 5.x.

Do we need to perform re-index elastic search data as part of migration ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Data written with Elasticsearch 2.x (Lucene 5) can be read by Elasticsearch 5.x (Lucene 6) without a reindex. Generally, Lucene can always write in its current version format and read the previous one; but it cannot read the one before. So if you had data written with Elasticsearch 1.x you would need to reindex, going from 2.x to 5.x won't need it.

And if you are not already doing it, use the [migration plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration/tree/2.x) to see what needs to be changed before the upgrade.

Comment: We are using the mapper attachment plugin to index PDF and other documents in elastic search 2.3.4 server. I did full cluster restart as part of migration, but it failed with mapper exceptions.   It is due to ingest plugin installed in elastic search 5.5 as replacement for mapper attachment plugin. Request your help to resolve the above mapping issue in migration the data from 2.3.4 to 5.5 version

Comment: Open a new question with the actual errors and what you are trying to do. And always use the migration helper and check deprecation logs before the upgrade